# Como llamar API externa desde Django-GraphQL para trabajar con ella?

Tags: python, django, api, graphql

Estoy trabajando con Graphene en Django, pero necesito tener los datos de una api externa [jumpsellerapi](https://jumpseller.com/support/api/) donde ya tengo el acceso con el login y la api key.
Como puedo llamar por ejemplo la lista de clientes de esta api para integrar esos datos a mi proyecto y mostrarlos por medio de graphql?

Soy nuevo en esto de las apis y graphql.

Segun he visto con la libreria [Requestes de python](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) lo puedo hacer, pero no estoy seguro como.